# Web Scraping using Selenium with two drop down menus

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a web scraper that cycles through two drop down menus, but I cannot seem to locate the first drop down box using selenium. I was to cycle through all the names, and years in the drop down box and export a table of all pages and values to a csv. The webpage is :http://surge.srcc.lsu.edu/s1.html

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://surge.srcc.lsu.edu/s1.html")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="storm_name"]')
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
```

My error is:

```
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id=\"storm_name\"]"}
```

Comment: Its because you are not loading the right webpage to find your element. [Your webpage](http://surge.srcc.lsu.edu/s1.html) contains an iFrame that points to [the actual content](http://surge.srcc.lsu.edu/surge_map.html) but Selenium I believe is not able to pre-load iFrames. Get this page and your code should work.

Comment: @Krazor you should post that as an answer

Comment: I was not sure if it was one. Will do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So because of [@HumphreyTriscuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436029/web-scraping-using-selenium-with-two-drop-down-menus?noredirect=1#comment60491331_36436029) I will post this as an answer. Please take the time to mark it as an answer in case it was.

So there you go:

Its because you are not loading the right webpage to find your element. [Your webpage](http://surge.srcc.lsu.edu/s1.html) contains an iFrame that points to the [actual content](http://surge.srcc.lsu.edu/surge_map.html) but Selenium I believe is not able to pre-load iFrames. Get this page and your code should work.

And also a little bonus right here: If you are unsure about your xPath you should consider using [xPath Checker for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/).

Comment: Yup, I was just working on this and found this out, re-posted my new code, my error is now that I run it, it selects the last element in the drop down box. I added sleep() b/c the implicit wait did not work.

Comment: `ImplicitWait` is a pain in Selenium and has very bad documentation. You should always use `ExplicitWait` with `WebDriverWait` however this can be hard too and is really ugly to read most of the times. Using sleep is bad practice overall but I guess an acceptable solution.